# How to Compare two dictionaries and substitute a string from the value

Tags: python

I have 2 dictionary

- I need to check the values of keys of `d2` in `d1` by passing `code`, `Name`, `module`
- if all matches then extract `details` from the `d2` then split by `|` and take the length of it
- Then check the length of above and `count(%s)` from d1
- if both are same then extract `MessageRole` and construct a `Message` from d1

```
d1 = [ { "Name": "Country", "module": "Request", "code": 11101, "Message": "Data Approved %s", "MessageRole": "Country User" }, { "Name": "Country", "module": "Request", "code": 11102, "Message": "Data Granted %s", "MessageRole": "Country User" }, { "Name": "Country", "module": "Request", "code": 11103, "Message": "Data Denied %s %s", "MessageRole": "Country User" }, { "Name": "Country", "module": "Request", "code": 11201, "Message": "Data Request %s %s %s", "MessageRole": "Data Owner" } ]
```

```
d2 = { "Name" : "Country", "module": "Request", "code" : 11201, "details": "A|B|C" }
```

My code is below

```
Role = ''
Message = ''
for each in d1:
    #I need to check the values of keys of `d2` in `d1` by passing `code`, `Name`, `module`
    if each["code"] == d2['code'] and \
            each["Name"] == d2['Name'] and \
            each["module"] == d2['module']:     
        #if all matches then extract `details` from the `d2` then split by `|` and take the length of it
        details = tuple(d2['details'].split('|'))
        print(details)
        variables = len(details)
        print(variables)
        # Then check the length of above and `count(%s)` from d1 
        if variables == each["Message"].count('%s'):
            # if both are same then extract `MessageRole` and construct a `Message` from d1
            Role = each["MessageRole"]
            Message = each["Message"] % ("<i>%s</i>"  % details)
```

Expected out is below

My `Role` will be having

```
Data Owner
```

My `Message` will be having

```
Data Request <i>A</i> <i>B</i> <i>C</i>
```

Comment: You showed the expected output, but what output are you currently getting?

Comment: does this even run? you are iterating over the keys of  `d1` as `each`, and strings are not subscriptable by other strings. `"Name"["code"]` will fail, and that's effectively what you're doing on line 5

Comment: @TedBrownlow TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Message = each["Message"] % ("<i>%s</i>"  % details)
```

to

```
Message = each["Message"]  % tuple("<i>%s</i>" % detail for detail in details)
```

and it will work as expected.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
Message = each["Message"].replace("%s","<i>%s</i>") % details
```

which is a bit shorter.

The problem is that (with your date) `details` has 3 items so `("<i>%s</i>"  % details)` doesn't make sense. You only need the first detail for that one string, hence the `not all arguments converted during string formatting` error message.